# PHP wamp, mail server no working after everything is fine

Tags: php, smtp

My sendmail config is

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
default_domain=localhost
error_logfile=error.log
;debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=www.nik357@gmail.com
auth_password=************
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=www.nik357@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=localhost
```

php.ini config

```
SMTP =
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_path = "‪C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
sendmail_from = www.nik357@gmail.com
```

I have set sendmail.exe properties as follows,
1. sendmail properties
2. compatibility
3. compatibility modes -> windows service pack 3
4. run the program as an administrator. 
My php script is

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Mail</title>


</head>
<body>
<?php
$to = "allen.titan357@gmail.com";
$sub = "Hi! my first SMTP mail.";
$txt = "Hope it has worked correctly";
$header = "From: donotreply@rmt.com" . "\r\n" . "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
if(mail($to, $sub, $txt, $header)){
    echo "E-mail sent";
}else{
    echo "Sending failed";
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

But still not working .I have looked for all the topic about this on stackoverflow but not working any one of them, please any solution.

It is showing the folowing massage on my webpage

Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\Titan_store\mail.php on line 14

Comment: I would change your gmail password right away. It's not a good idea at all to post it here... And note that if you edit the question, a history remains, so you should really change the password of the account itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't see when I  copied and pasted in .

Comment: And please describe what 'not working' means. Did you get "Sending failed", or does the mail just not arrive. If the latter, it might be due to the sender. Gmail may check if the computer you are sending from is allowed to send mail on behalf of rmt.com